# MiKTeX update: a too old babel/frenchb

Tags: miktex, babel, updating, french

This question deals with the version of a `babel` language available after a MiKTeX update (the french one, namely `frenchb.dtx`). I've just made an update of my (complete) MiKTeX 2.9, especially interested in the package `menukeys` and in `frenchb`; the result of the update is (with a `\listfiles`):

- `frenchb.ldf`    2009/03/16 v2.3d
- `menukeys.sty`    2012/04/11 v1.1b

However, `menukeys` requires a feature from a more recent `frenchb` to avoid a ''french bug'' (if not mistaken, on CTAN there is `frenchb.dtx` 2010/08/21 v2.5a).

Questions: does my problem (= not having a recent enough version of `frenchb` after a MiKTeX update) come from MiKTeX? If yes, could MiKTeX provide that version 2.5? or is there something preventing it?

(My temporary solution is to manually update `frenchb` as suggested by its author... it works fine but I still wonder why I can't get it from the MiKTeX update).

Comment: The current version of frenchb (on the website of the author) is 2012/05/08 v2.5j. So the version on CTAN is outdated too. Beside this: It sometimes happens that miktex (and TeXLive too) forgets to package an updated package. Make a bug report or a feature request.

Comment: Are you sure to have MiKTeX 2.9?

Comment: @egreg: No, both Mathieu (?) and Ulrike are right.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Feature request done (you did mean on MiKTeX homepage?).

Answer (score 2):

My MiKTeX paket manager shows the used `babel` is from 2011-07-11, a `frenchb` is not separatly listed, but there is a package `frenchle` from 2012-06-11 usable with or without `babel`.

To use package `frenchb` the installation in the local texmf tree seems actualy to be the best.

I think the best place to ask is the maintainer of MiKTeX on the MiKTeX homepage.